# How do I make my image in a flexbox row stretch to the maximum width of my container

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I would like to stretch itself out so there is no whitespace on the right whilst maintaining its aspect ratio and just cutting some of the image out of view. I also want to have the image the same size as the blue container.
I tried some solutions on here such as setting the max width of the image to 100% and using object-fit: cover I but haven't figured it out yet.
[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.see-bike-rides-card {
  display: flex;
  max-height:400px;
}

.home-card-text {
  background: #80D0E5;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.see-bike-rides-card {
  max-height: 400px;
  width: 1000px;
}

.see-bike-rides-card img {
  width: fit-content;
  max-height:400px;
  object-fit: cover;

}
```

```html
<article class="see-bike-rides-card">

  <section class="home-card-text">
    <h2>Coolest Bike Rides in Brisbane</h2>
    <p>Check out our favourite spots
      to ride your bike in Brissy.</p>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="button">See Bike Trails</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515722265856-49cdff079949?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8" alt="">
    </figure>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Is `object-fit: fill` meet your demand?

Comment: i tried it but it sadly didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the sections to be 50% width so they are equal, then set the figure to be 100% height & width to fill the space, with object-fit cover will get the image to fill the area.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.see-bike-rides-card {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}

.see-bike-rides-card section {
  width: 50%;
}

.home-card-text {
  background: #80D0E5;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.see-bike-rides-card figure {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
.see-bike-rides-card img {
  object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article class="see-bike-rides-card">

  <section class="home-card-text">
    <h2>Coolest Bike Rides in Brisbane</h2>
    <p>Check out our favourite spots
      to ride your bike in Brissy.</p>
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="button">See Bike Trails</a>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515722265856-49cdff079949?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8" alt="">
    </figure>
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: when you run this code by clicking expand snippet unfortunately it is not filling the screen

Comment: Thats just the height of the .see-bike-rides-card, change the min-height/max-height values to get what you want.

Comment: it is the width, i can share a picture if you need

Comment: I just added 100vh to the .see-bike-rides-card it will now fill the screen.

Answer (score 0):

In

.see-bike-rides-card

Change max width to 100% as well.

Comment: with width at 100% it doesnt change anything.
You have to click the expand snippet button to see the code snippet in full screen I should have stated that in the post sorry

Answer (score 0):

Using inline-style will only solve the problem you can use max-width or width:

```
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515722265856-49cdff079949?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8" style="max-width=100%; object-fit:contain"alt="">
```

Comment: Try the inline-style I added to the image